# Cannot get Bootstrap to work with Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to learn Rails and during this time I wanted to make my pages a little more stylish. To do so I went ahead and downloaded Bootstrap 4 and followed all the installation instructions I could find. To test it I tried to add a simple navigation bar. The bar loads all the text fine but there is no CSS applied to it :(

All the bootstrap css and js files are in assets/stylesheet and /javascript

At this point I am not too sure what I am doing wrong or what needs to be changed. I am guessing it is something simple.

Gemfile

> gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
>
> gem 'execjs'
>
> gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
>
> gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
>
> gem 'coffee-script-source', '~> 1.8.0'
>
> gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha6'
>
> gem 'jquery-rails'

Application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Test</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', media: 'all', "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    </head>
    <body>  
    <nav class="navbar navbar">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
        <div class="container">
            <%= yield %>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is my
/assets/stylesheets/application.scss

> @import "bootstrap";

This is my /assets/javascript/application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap.js
//= require bootstrap.min.js
//= require jquery-3.1.1.min.js
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .
```

Thank you

Comment: You should remove the duplicates `require` statements from your `application.js`. You are loading jquery and bootstrap multiple times. As @Uday kumar das said, make sure you're loading `bootstrap-sprockets`, instead of `bootstrap`.

Do you have any errors in the javascript console?

Comment: I have removed the duplicates but nothing has changed. I also added `@import "bootstrap-sprockets"` to the application.scss file at the beginning but nothing :(

Answer (score 0):

I Think I found the issue.
I had two sass entries in the gemfile

```
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3.6'
```

I commented out sass-rails and everything started working.